# ParseServer: Who to create a temporary file in Cloud Code and send it to browser

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I want to generate a file (PDF, txt, csv, ...) in a parse cloud code function and send it directly as download to the browser without saving it on the server.

Is there a possibility to modify the cloud code response (headers, body)?
Or is there an other way to achieve this?

Comment: I think you will not be able to do that using the cloud code. You will have to create your own endpoint for doing that. Where/how are you running your Parse Server? Is it an Express.js application?

Comment: Yes, i have my own vm for that. Alternatively, i could create a Parse File, store it temporarly (delete with a job) to the mobodb and return the download link of that file. Would that be a good idea?

Comment: You can do this but you can only delete the file after the client has downloaded it. I think it would be better you create a custom endpoint in your Express.js application.